# AWS IAM Policy wildchar and restricted access

Tags: amazon-web-services, policy, amazon-iam

Hi I have a IAM policy with following snippet with statement as follow:-

```html
...
{
         "Effect"   : "Allow",
         "Action"   : "dynamodb:*",
         "Resource" : [
                       "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/sampletable",
                       "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/*",
                       "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/*/stream/*"
                       ]
         }
..
```

What happens in this case where there is restricted table/sampletable and a wildchar ?

I could not get the answer to this on documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the

```
"arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/*",
```

resource specification will be considered, since it has a wider scope, effectively "overriding" the other, so the `table/*` will also match the `table/sampletable` resource.

I'm not sure why are you calling that table "restricted". If you're trying to restrict access to sampletable, you need to add another policy statement, with `Effect: Deny` and specify in the Resource list sampletable's ARN. In such case, the request will be denied because `Deny` has precedence. See [Determining Whether a Request is Allowed or Denied](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-denyallow).

Comment: Thanks @simone , When I edited the policy using Visual Editor , I got this wiered policy . I was wondering if its least priviledge or not. Thanks for the update